# Is there anyway to use Client side analytics API(7.1) for MobileFirst Analytics Server version 8.0?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

We have App center codebase of(7.1) and server verison of 8.0. We want to implement analytics for the hybrid App Center v7.1

Answer (score 0):

MFP 8.0 Operational Analytics can only log analytics data from apps created with the MFP 8.0 SDK.  It can't be used to log analytics data from apps created with prior versions of MFP - among other reasons, the Elasticsearch mappings are different.  (Well, it's certainly possible that the MFP 8.0 Operational Analytics server may receive and store data into Elasticsearch from apps build with prior versions of MFP, but such data would not show up in the analytics dashboard, due to the different mappings.)

Comment: But we are able to see the analytics data in console for the adapters built in 8.0